# Access the controller scope on another controller

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angular. I want to access the one controller scope on another first I want to know the simple way and available way to do this, advance thanks

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="fName"><br><br>
        Last Name : <input type="text" ng-model="lName">
        <p ng-bind="fullName()"></p>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="mySecondCtrl">
        Father Name: <input type="text" ng-model="fathName"><br><br>
        Mother Name:<input type="text" ng-model="mothName">
        <p>
        <strong>Paren name:</strong>
        <span>Mr.{{fathName}},</span>
        <span>Ms.{{mothName}}</span>
        </p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

        app.controller("myCtrl",myFunction);
        function myFunction($scope){
            $scope.fName = "";
            $scope.lName = "";
            $scope.fullName = function(){
                return $scope.fName +" "+ $scope.lName
            }
        }
        app.controller("mySecondCtrl",mySecondFunction);
        function mySecondFunction($scope){
            //I want to access the fullName() function here
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: use `$braodcast` and `$on` function for relation two controller or use `factory` to share data between controllers

Comment: thanks [Matthew Walton](http://stackoverflow.com/users/241544/matthew-walton)

Comment: you should be learning AngularJS 2, what you are doing Google has clearly stated they have found better ways in AngularJS 2

Comment: You can also nest controllers. This way child controller can access parent controller scope. Though not recommended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this purpose by using Angular services for data transfer. You need to set your method in `myCtrl`, `$scope.fullName` to a data transfer service.

Now the service holds your method in a variable. Now from your second controller, `mySecondCtrl`, access the method in the data transfer service.

Now in effect you have called the method in the first controller from the second one. Here is the working  example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        First Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="fName">
        <br>
        <br> Last Name :
        <input type="text" ng-model="lName">
        <p ng-bind="fullName()"></p>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="mySecondCtrl">
        Father Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="fathName">
        <br>
        <br> Mother Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="mothName">
        <p>
            <strong>Paren name:</strong>
            <span>Mr.{{fathName}},</span>
            <span>Ms.{{mothName}}</span>
        </p>
        <p><button ng-click="getDetails()">Get Details</button></p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

        app.controller("myCtrl", myFunction);

        function myFunction($scope, DataTransfer) {
            $scope.fName = "";
            $scope.lName = "";
            $scope.fullName = function () {
                //console.log('fullname method called');
                return $scope.fName + " " + $scope.lName
            }
            //Setting the method to a data transfer service
            DataTransfer.setUserDetails($scope.fullName);
        }



        app.controller("mySecondCtrl", mySecondFunction);

        function mySecondFunction($scope, DataTransfer) {
            //I want to access the fullName() function here
            $scope.getDetails = function () {
                console.log('Going to call fullname method from second controller');
                //Reading the method in first controller inside the second one
                var functionItem = DataTransfer.getUserDetails();
                var details = functionItem();
                console.log(details);
            }
        }

        app.factory('DataTransfer', function () {

            var data = {};

            return {
                getUserDetails: function () {
                    return data;
                },
                setUserDetails: function (UserDetails) {
                    data = UserDetails;
                }
            };
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

> Modifications

Here the method is received in a variable in the second controller(`functionItem`) and that method is called and response data is saved in a variable(`details`). Now the variable `details` holds the user details which was taken from first controller.

Comment: How I get the full name on second ???

Comment: @SrikrushnaPal I have updated the answer.

Comment: thank you @Nitheesh